# How to remove 'stargazer' on my GitHub repo?

Tags: github

I recently noticed some bot users starring my repo.

`https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/stargazers`

I wanted to know how I can remove these bot user who starred my repo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [block](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/maintaining-your-safety-on-github/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account) them:

> When you block a user:
>
> - The user's stars and issue assignments are removed from your
>   repositories
>
> After you've blocked a user, they cannot:
>
> - Fork, watch, pin, or star your repositories